# Port forwarding with IP restriction on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have the following scenario:

Service network that is used by administrators of the system, it is behind NAT and uses public IP adress (Let's call it EnabledSourceIP)

Production network> Machine1 (Windows Server 2012 R2), External IP, Port 1500 Machine2 (Windows Server 2012 R2), Internal IP, Port 1433

We would like to configure port forwarding where clients connected from EnabledSourceIP would be able to connect to ExternalIP:1500, from there the packets would be forwarded to InternalIP:1433.

Simply said, it's should be just port forwarding Machine1:1500->Machine2:1433 with IP restriction to EnabledSourceIP (as a remote address).

We tried to use this:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1500 listenaddress=1.2.3.4 connectport=1433 connectaddress=192.168.1.5 (IP addresseses are dummy)

Then we set Firewall rule to allow Inbound connection to 1.2.3.4:1500 for remote address EnabledSourceIP. The connection works, BUT: The IP restriction does not. Any client from any IP is able to connect to 1.2.3.4:1500, it looks like if the scope setting was ignored. Which is no good, because this way the machine would be opened publicly for everyone and it simply cannot be.

We also tried not to use netsh portproxy and tested port forwarding utility PassPort, which behaves the same way. Connection can be done, firewall restrictoin is ignored.

Do you have any idea how to solve our problem?

Kind regards, Jan

Comment: Did you ever get an answer/solution to this? I have exactly the same requirement. Thanks.